# Database SQLite issue in Android?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I want delivery charge compared to subtotal and calculate delivery charges. I got the result successfully.
I get query and I put in that code execute in Execute SQL. I got correct answer. But

I have some problem in retrieve data. I got result everytime first position value only .

Below I have mention my code.Give me solution.

```
String Query ="select ROUND(delivarycharge) from pincodedetails where ROUND(subtotal)
<= ( select ROUND(subtotal)  from pincodedetails where ROUND(subtotal) >= "+price+" 
and resturantID="+selArgs+" limit 1) and resturantID ="+selArgs+" and ROUND(subtotal) 
>= ( select ROUND(subtotal) from pincodedetails where ROUND(subtotal) <= "+price+" 
and resturantID="+selArgs+" limit 1)  order by ROUND(subtotal) LIMIT 1";
```

**Database Helper Class:**

```
double deliverycharge= 0;
if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
    // Got first result
    deliverycharge= mCursor.getDouble(0);
}
return deliverycharge;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change your code to retrieve to something like:

```
Vector<String> temp = new Vector<String>;
cursor.moveToFirst();
do {

    deliverycharge= mCursor.getDouble(0);
    temp.add()                  
} while (cursor.moveToNext());
return temp;
```

So you will return a vetor containing all Strings.

Comment: i got only one result sunhari.No need list and all

Comment: If you need to retrieve all strings then how can you do without vector or list or String[]? @Gomathi

Comment: Because every time String will be overwritten @Gomathi

Comment: I don't need all string value just only one string For example 40 only

Comment: And how is that decided? I mean which String do you need? Is it always first column data? @Gomathi

Comment: K how to make delivery charge in Vector<String>?

Comment: how to make added delivery charge in Vector<String>?

Comment: Do you mean how to retrieve it? It can be done by temp.get(0), temp.get(1), etc @Gomathi

Comment: How to retrieve data with out use cursor any possible?

Comment: Do u mean retrieve data from database without cursor? Not possible. @Gomathi

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String Query ="select ROUND(delivarycharge) as roundcharge from pincodedetails where ROUND(subtotal) <=( select ROUND(subtotal)  from pincodedetails where ROUND(subtotal)>="+price+" and resturantID="+selArgs+" limit 1) and resturantID="+selArgs+" and ROUND(subtotal) >=( select ROUND(subtotal) from pincodedetails where ROUND(subtotal)<="+price+" and resturantID="+selArgs+" limit 1)  order by ROUND(subtotal) LIMIT 1";
```

You need the as "whatever name you want"